# How to use custom meta added in WP e-Commerce plugin

Tags: wordpress

I want to display a unique header image for each product added through WP e-Commerce plugin.

I have added URL of image in Custom Meta under Advanced Settings heading.

I am not able to figure out how to get data added in Custom Meta of WP e-Commerce plugin in header.php?

Any suggestions please.

---

Update:

I tried following code found in wpsc-single-product.php

```
if (wpsc_have_custom_meta()) :
    while ( wpsc_have_custom_meta() ) : wpsc_the_custom_meta();
        $product_meta = wpsc_custom_meta_value();
    endwhile;
endif;
```

This shows following error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function have_custom_meta() on a non-object in wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/wpsc-includes/product-template.php on line 1304

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would depend on where you placed that code. If you did not enter it after line 29:

```
while ( wpsc_have_products() ) : wpsc_the_product();
```

...then it's not within The Loop and getting custom meta data will result in an error.

Comment: Thanks @annedorko, i wrapped my code inside the products look, and it's working now.

Comment: The loop becomes infinite when used in a custom WP_Query, rather than a single page